# How to show next time slots from the current time

Tags: laravel, time

I am trying to show next time slots from the current time.

Table contains the time slots `'time' = 12:00 AM, 10:00 AM, 12:00 PM, 02:00 PM, 05:00 PM, 08:00 PM, 10:00 PM`

I just want to show the upcoming time slots from the current time. The time slots remaining for today will show in today array and the next time slots in tomorrow array.

```
$now = Carbon::now()->format('g:i A');
$time = TimeSlot::where('time', '<', $now)->get();         
$data = array('message'=>ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_DATA_FOUND), 'timeSlots'=>$time, 'current_time'=>$now);
return $this->sendSuccessResponse($data);
```

Output is :

```
{
    "message": "Data retrieve Successfully",
    "timeSlots": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "time": "12:00 AM"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "time": "10:00 AM"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "time": "12:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "time": "02:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "time": "05:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "time": "08:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "time": "10:00 PM"
        }
    ],
    "current_time": "5:16 PM",
    "status": true
}
```

Reuired Output will be something like this:

```
{
    "message": "Data retrieve Successfully",
    "timeSlots": [
        {
            "today": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "time": "08:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "time": "10:00 PM"
                }
            ],
            "tomorrow": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "time": "12:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "time": "10:00 AM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "time": "12:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "time": "02:00 PM"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "time": "05:00 PM"
                }
            ],
        } 
    ],
    "current_time": "5:16 PM",
    "status": true
}
```

Please help me out,

Comment: Do you have flexibility to modify the format of the `TimeSlot` table entries? If so, you could change the column type to use a `TIME` column (`$table->time('time');` in your migration) and let Eloquent handle the comparisons

Answer (score 0):

In case you can't modify your table to store info in a more useful way (as suggested in my comment), you can do at the collection level. For this, I'm making use of the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map) and [`partition()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-partition) collection methods. Given that the first method returns the same collection instance, it allows us to chain the methods.

```
list($tomorrow, $today) = TimeSlot::all()
        // Here we create a new field that will contain a carbon instance of the time
        ->map(function ($slot) {
            $slot['timeTemp'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('g:i A', $slot['time']);

            return $slot;
        })
        // Then we partition the collection using the current time,
        // this will return two collections
        ->partition(function ($slot) {
            return $slot['timeTemp'] < now();
        });

$timeSlots = [
  'today' => $today,
  'tomorrow' => $tomorrow,
];

$data = [
    'message' => ResponseMessage::statusResponses(ResponseMessage::_STATUS_DATA_FOUND),
    'timeSlots' => $timeSlots,
    'current_time' => Carbon::now()->format('g:i A'),
];

return $this->sendSuccessResponse($data);
```

Of course, this will also return the `'timeTemp'` value that we inserted in each time slot, but you can ignore them or remove them by mapping through each slot again. Up to you.